# How to dynamically show passions related to user that has been searched?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I wish to display the passions for all the user that was displayed in the search results. Currently, this isnt dynamic, how do I make this dynamic? As I have to include the [0],[1],[2].. manually. I am using cakephp. The following code is located in my view.ctp page.

```
foreach ($data as $user) {
$cell .= $user['Passion'][0]['tag'].' '.$user['Passion'][1]['tag'].' '.$user['Passion'][2]['tag'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about a double foreach loop?

```
foreach ($data as $user) {
    foreach ($user['Passion'] as $passion) { 
        $cell.= $passion['tag']; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: and you can use Gustav Bertrams method to create the spaces between, of course

Answer (score 0):

The following code iterates through every tag, and also puts a space between each tag.

```
foreach ($data as $user) {
    $passions = array(); //Reset the line

    foreach ($user['Passion'] as $passion) { 
        array_push($passions, $passion['tag']); // Add each tag
    } 

    $cell.= implode($passions, ' '); // Put a space between each tag
}
```